# Multi-dimension input to a neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a neural network with many layers. I have the input to the neural network of dimension `[batch_size, 7, 4]`. When this input is passed through the network, I observed that only the third dimension of the input keeps changing, that is if my first layer has 20 outputs, then the output of the second layer is `[batch_size, 7, 20]`. I need the end result after many layers to be of the shape `[batchsize, 16]`.

I have the following questions:

- Are the other two dimensions being used at all?
- If not, how can I modify my network so that all three dimensions are used?
- How do I drop one dimension meaningfully to get the 2-d output that I desire?

Following is my current implementation in **Tensorflow v1.14** and **Python 3**:

```py
out1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=noisy_data, units=150, activation=tf.nn.tanh)  # Outputs [batch, 7, 150]
out2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=out1, units=75, activation=tf.nn.tanh)  # Outputs [batch, 7, 75] 
out3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=out2, units=32, activation=tf.nn.tanh)  # Outputs [batch, 7, 32]
out4 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=out3, units=16, activation=tf.nn.tanh)  # Outputs [batch, 7, 16]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question 1**: The data values in 2nd dimension (`axis=1`) are not being used because if you look at the output of code snippet below (assuming `batch_size=2`):

```
>>> input1 = tf.placeholder(float, shape=[2,7,4])
>>> tf.layers.dense(inputs=input1, units=150, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
>>> graph = tf.get_default_graph()
>>> graph.get_collection('variables')
[<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(4, 150) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(150,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

you can see that the `dense` layer ignores values along 2nd dimension. However, the values along 1st dimension would be considered as it is a part of a *batch* though the offical [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) doesn't say anything about the required input shape.

**Answer to Question 2**: [Reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) the input `[batch_size, 7, 4]` to `[batch_size, 28]` by using the below line of code before passing the input to the first `dense` layer:

```
input1 = tf.reshape(input1, [-1, 7*4])
```

**Answer to Question 3**: If you *reshape* the inputs as above, there is no need to drop a dimension.

Comment: sorry for replying so late. The reason I have the data in 3 dimensions is that they carry some meaning in each of the dimension. `reshape` will help in reducing dimension, no problem, but the data is now interleaved and has lost all its meaning. That's what I mean by "meaningful" in my question. In short, though you've successfully reduced one dimension, it doesn't help. Thanks